# Variables in named.conf

Tags: bind, named-conf

My server have one IP and several domains hosted.

One and same IP appear in named.conf and several zone files.

When the IP address of the server changes, I need manually to change all those IP's.

Is there a way to do something like:

in named.conf:

```
#define $IP 123.123.123.123
```

zone file:

```
        MX 10     mail
        A         $IP
www     A         $IP
mail    A         $IP
*       CNAME     www
```

any help will be appretiated

Answer (score 4):

Well, if the IP Address is always the same for `@`, `www` and `mail`, you can add an `$INCLUDE` directive to your zone files (see [here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/include.html)).

Ideally, create a `commons.db` zone file with your common zone descriptions:

```
@        IN    A    1.2.3.4
wwww     IN    A    1.2.3.4
mail     IN    A    1.2.3.4
*        IN    CNAME    www
```

and then in your domain zone files simply do:

```
@        IN    MX 10    mail
$INCLUDE  commons.db
```

Comment: not a bad idea, but what if my zones using 4-5 IP's in mixed way.
can I somehow include just the IP ?

Comment: @Nick do you mean having different IPs for @, www and mail records? Or some domains on 1 IP, some on differnt IP and so on? Or some domains have IP 1.2.3.4 for www and 5.6.7.8 for mail, while some other the other way around (5.6.7.8 for www and 1.2.3.4 for mail0?

Comment: to be exact, the server have 4 IP's
one is for web, another is for static content, another for different kind of web. each zone is different, but have one or more of these IP's.

Comment: @Nick then I fear you're out of luck. How many zones are we talking about? I think that a simple `sed 's/OLD.IP.ADD.RESS/NEW.IP.ADD.RESS/'` every now and then (how often do these IP change?) won't be too much of a hassle.

Comment: i'm doing it similar to this

Comment: @MrShunz link broken.

Comment: @JacobEvans link still works fine from here (http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/include.html)

Comment: I fixed it for you